# IE will not continue with server response after browser detection, why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser, event-listener, browser-detection

I am creating a tracking tool that logging button clicks into a database from any domain.

I wanted to use Web Workers, but the list of browsers that support this limited so...  I added browser detection to send them down the correct path.

My issues is that once I added the browser detection to IE I no longer get a server response, (post, redirect, nothing)  Am I doing something wrong?

This where the buttons are being detected

```
            if ((isIE) && (isIE == true)) {

            function addBtnClickListener(e) {
                var btnClicked = this;

                var eventType = "button.click";
                var ctrBtnText = btnClicked.value;
                track(btnClicked, eventType, '', '', ctrBtnText, '', '', '', btnClicked);

                return false;
            }
        }
        else if ((isChrome) && (isChrome == true) || (isFirefox) && (isFirefox == true) || (isSafari) && (isSafari == true) || (isOpera) && (isOpera == true)) {
            //WEB WORKERS
            if (typeof SharedWorker != 'undefined') { //shared web worker is supported

                //Shared Worker
                function addBtnClickListener() {
                    var btnClicked = this;

                    var eventType = "button.click";
                    var ctrBtnText = btnClicked.value;
                    track(btnClicked, eventType, '', '', ctrBtnText, '', '', '', null, btnClicked);

                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (typeof (Worker) != "undefined") { //web worker is supported

                //Web Worker
                function addBtnClickListener(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var btnClicked = this;

                    var eventType = "button.click";
                    var ctrBtnText = btnClicked.value;
                    track(btnClicked, eventType, '', '', ctrBtnText, '', '', '', btnClicked, null);
                    //this.click();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            else {
                //function addBtnClickListener(e) {
                var btnClicked = this;

                var eventType = "button.click";
                var ctrBtnText = btnClicked.value;
                track(btnClicked, eventType, '', '', ctrBtnText, '', '', '', btnClicked);

                return false;
                //}
            }
        }
        else { }
```

This is where they are being logged

```
        if ((isIE) && (isIE == true)) {

            console.log("IE");

            doRequestMethod(url);

            function GetXmlHttpObject() {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    //for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    return new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    //for IE6, IE5
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                return null;
            }

            function doRequestMethod(url) {
                var xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
                if (xmlhttp == null) {
                    console.log("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
                    return;
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send(url);
            }

        }
        else if ((isChrome) && (isChrome == true) || (isFirefox) && (isFirefox == true) || (isSafari) && (isSafari == true) || (isOpera) && (isOpera == true)) {

            //WORKS AS IT SHOULD

        }
        else { }
```

Once I remove the IE detection detection the form works correctly in IE, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Then why show the code for all other scenarios? Did you remove those and isolate the problem in IE with the related code alone? Please, do. Then, if the problem persists, return with the minimal amount of code required to reproduce it.

Comment: The issue is here if ((isIE) && (isIE == true)) {//something happens}  for some reason when I do this in IE nothing happens on the server side, remove it everything works in IE, but no where else.  I was thinking something in the other code may be the cause...no?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `console` in IE is only true if you have the Dev tools activated (F12), so see if it's really that simple (your script stops after the console exception and only in IE)...hth....

Comment: The console logs appear as they should and the entry makes it to the database.  The problem is that's where it stops.  Doesn't move onto the "thank you" page, do a post back, nothing